# Unable to write data to AWS RDS PostgreSQL database?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-application-load-balancer

In my Django application, I'm utilizing AWS RDS PostgreSQL as my database backend. I've encountered an issue when attempting to send a POST request to store data in the database. After a period of loading, I receive a '502 Bad Gateway' error. Interestingly, I can successfully read data from the database.

I also have a mobile app and a separate front-end application developed in Vue.js. When making POST requests from the mobile app, all operations work flawlessly, except for the one related to OTP, which also gives a '502' error. Other CRUD operations from the app are functioning as expected. In addition, reading and writing data works properly from the Django admin panel and the dashboard, both of which are built in Django.

Within the front-end application, I can write data successfully, but I encounter a '502' error when attempting to write. This issue specifically occurs when I add CNAME of Application Load Balancer's DNS point to the domain. However, if I use an IP address in the A record to point to the domain, everything functions as expected.

What could be the source of this issue and how can it be resolved?

I added some details:
[This is listner rules SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCJLU.png)

[This is ALB details SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvopW.png)

[This is ALB SG SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYeeJ.png)

[This is TG SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qa7k.png)

**NGINX SETTINGS**

```
server {

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    error_log /var/www/app/app-backend/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /var/www/app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        proxy_pass https://appbkt.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/app/gunicorn.sock;
      proxy_send_timeout 300;
      proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

[This is update instance view. This view take request from front-end application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p86Gc.png)

[This view takes request from flutter app. This responsible for generate otp and send in response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzREz.png)

**This added in django settings.py file**

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://www.example.com', 'https://example.com','https://app-alb-asg-3817902479.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com'
                        ]
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Comment: Please provide more details about :  configuration of ALB if you use it (especially listener rules) ; configuration of the web server ; in Django, any details about your urlconf, and finally, the code of the view.

Comment: And also do you use a WAF ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the post by adding some details that you mentioned. @0urz4g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to your SSL setup.
I don't understand why you have defined a listener on ALB for port 443 with a certificate, and in the same time, a port 443 listener on nginx with also a certificate.
The common way to do is to setup SSL on ALB, and forward everything to port 80 on nginx. You can avoid handling SSL on nginx.

So I would advice to review your nginx configuration to have juste one server block on port 80 ; then change your ALB setup to redirect any HTTP request to HTTPS (with a redirect rule), and to forward port 443 to port 80 on your ec2 instance.

Comment: I did this, in nginx i add one server block with listen 80. and Alb listner rule is 443 with SSL certificate, which forward target group to port 80. But still same issue, read works but write not.

Comment: can you please show the entire code of the view ?

Comment: I got another clue when I deregistered the instance created by auto-scaling, and registered the instance that I created, it worked fine. The difference is auto scale instance with private IP, and instance I created have public IP. I checked private instance subnet and rds instance subnet are same, also vpc.

Comment: I got another thing. If i register a instance with public IP, everything work fine, if register instance with private IP, db write operation not working, auto scale create instance with private ip.
@0urz4g

Comment: It seems like  you have a problem in your network setup. If you use a private subnet for your EC2 instances, you have to use a NAT to give them an internet access. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-in-vpc.html#as-vpc-considerations

Comment: Otherwise you can modify your auto scaling launch configuration to assign a public IP to each new instance

Comment: Thanks. It works, the problem occurs for the added private subnet when I remove the private subnet from the configuration, instance created with public IP. I am curious to know why to read works, and from the app end & django admin panel write also work, but does not work from frontend application.